# Blog menu link is set to current page when on Tag or Archive page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a menu defined that appears in my header. It contains a link to the Blog listing page.

When I navigate to the Blog Archive or Tag Archive, this menu item is set to the current page.

Why is it doing this?

Is there a way to stop it?

I know I can add conditional CSS to stop the item being highlighted by my CSS, but I'd like to know the reason why the current page class is added and if it can be changed.

Menu Defined in Functions.php

```
function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Menu displayed in template:

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu(array(
    'container' => '',
    'echo' => false,
    'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s list-inline">%3$s</ul>',
));
$menu = str_replace("\n", "", $menu);
$menu = str_replace("\r", "", $menu);
echo $menu;
```

Comment: It is default wordpress behaviour and wordpress code adds the `active` class to the current menu item. You can remove the class by using jQuery is you do not want to go the CSS way.

Comment: It's not adding `active`, it's adding `current_page_parent`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and replace `my-cat-tax`, `my-post-type` with your blog`s taxonomy and post type

```
function fix_blog_menu_css_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if ( is_tax( 'my-cat-tax' ) || is_singular( 'my-post-type' ) || is_post_type_archive( 'my-post-type' ) ) {
        if ( $item->object_id == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
            $key = array_search( 'current_page_parent', $classes );
            if ( false !== $key )
                unset( $classes[ $key ] );
        }
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'fix_blog_menu_css_class', 10, 2 );
```